# How to create new lists in python

Tags: python, python-3.x, list, function

I want to create new lists from one list. This the example list I am working on:

```
matrixlist = [['Matrix', '1'], ['1', '4', '6'], ['5', '2', '9'], ['Matrix', '2'], ['2', '6'], ['1', '3'], ['8', '6'], ['Matrix', '3'], ['5', '6', '7', '9'], ['1', '4', '2', '3'], ['8', '7', '3', '5'], ['9', '4', '5', '3'], ['Matrix', '4'], ['7', '8'], ['4', '6'], ['2', '3']]
```

I split them like this with for loop:

```
matrix1 = [['1', '4', '6'], ['5', '2', '9']]
matrix2 = [['2', '6'], ['1', '3'], ['8', '6']]
matrix3 = [['5', '6', '7', '9'], ['1', '4', '2', '3'], ['8', '7', '3', '5'], ['9', '4', '5', '3']]
matrix4 = [['7', '8'], ['4', '6'], ['2', '3']]
```

But I want to give the long list to program and it create lists and append the relevant elements in it. Like matrix 1 elements in matrix1 list.

Edit: I can't use any advanced built-in function. I can only use simple ones (like append, pop, reverse, range) and my functions in code.

Comment: What is wrong with the *for* loop approach? Are you going to have multiple matrices or there are always 4?

Comment: There is maybe more than 4. I edited the question maybe it is now clear.

Comment: If you can change the structure of the input list, I would highly recommend using a 2D array of matrices instead of the current structure. With a 2d array, your first matrix will simply be `matrixList[0]`, the second `matrixList[1]`, and so on.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

you can do it using list comprehension like below

```py
indx = [i  for i, mat in enumerate(matrixlist )if mat[0]=='Matrix']

matrixes = {matrixlist[i][1]: matrixlist[i+1: j] for i, j in zip(indx, indx[1:])}

# access matrix with its id
matrixes["1"]
```

Comment: Thanks, it is useful for me.

Answer (score 1):

You can use `itertools.groupby`:

```
from itertools import groupby
matrixlist = [['Matrix', '1'], ['1', '4', '6'], ['5', '2', '9'], ['Matrix', '2'], ['2', '6'], ['1', '3'], ['8', '6'], ['Matrix', '3'], ['5', '6', '7', '9'], ['1', '4', '2', '3'], ['8', '7', '3', '5'], ['9', '4', '5', '3'], ['Matrix', '4'], ['7', '8'], ['4', '6'], ['2', '3']]
result = [list(b) for a, b in groupby(matrixlist, key=lambda x:x[0] == 'Matrix') if not a]
```

Output:

```
[[['1', '4', '6'], ['5', '2', '9']], 
 [['2', '6'], ['1', '3'], ['8', '6']], 
 [['5', '6', '7', '9'], ['1', '4', '2', '3'], ['8', '7', '3', '5'], ['9', '4', '5', '3']], 
 [['7', '8'], ['4', '6'], ['2', '3']]]
```

Comment: Thanks but I can't use it. I want them in different lists to use them.